# Как получить размерность в dp

Tags: android

В файле `dimens.xml` есть строка `<dimen name="standart_text_size">18dp</dimen>`. Когда я пытаюсь получить размерность в `dp` (`(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standart_text_size)`), я получаю ее в пикселях(18dp*1.5)! Как ее получить в `dp`?

Comment: как насчет спросить у гугла `android get dimension dp`? Лень потратить 24 секунды своего времени? Ответ написать и то дольше займет.

Comment: @metalurgus, это с одной стороны. А с другой мы тут типа на русском базу данных собираем... Дилемма, да( По хорошему ТС надо было задать вопрос, погуглить и самому себе ответить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я вчера даже нашел ответ на enSO, но он отказался грузится и выдал ошибку, мол не может загрузить страницу. И так на все подобные вопросы.

Comment: @bukashka101, да, вчера SO был мёртв некоторое время(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, с наступающим! :D

Comment: @metalurgus, с наступающим! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, взаимно! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конкретно для размера текста:

```
 textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

В общем случае:

```
int dp = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)
```

Размер текста рекомендуется указывать в `sp`, а не `dp`, тогда будет учитываться размер текста, заданный в настройках системы. То есть, если человек плохо видит и в настройках системы установил "крупный текст", то своими `dp` в размере текста вы просто наплюете на его проблемы (и он не станет пользоваться вашим приложением). С `sp` его проблема будет учитываться и текст дополнительно масштабироваться.

Comment: Спасибо! Про `sp` я забыл, но еще вчера исправил. И случилось чудо! Я случайно наткнулся на Ваш ответ о книгах, про андроди. Буду потихоньку читать "Программирование под Android" 2014го года.

Comment: pavloff, с наступающим! :D